# How to check if there is a table on an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

**I have to make a VBA macro to check if there is a chart already present on an excel sheet. So, if there is any chart present, I have to delete it and if not, I have to put in a new chart.**

I tried using:
`Worksheets("Sheet.Name").ChartObjects.Delete` directly, but if a chart was not present on a sheet, it gave an error.

i also tried using  `ThisWorkbook.Charts.Count` but it is always showing that I have 0 charts in my workbook even though there are 2 charts on the first sheet itself.

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through all `ChartObjects` in your worksheet, and delete each one of them (if exists).

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckCharts()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

For Each ChtObj In Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects '<-- modify "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
    ChtObj.Delete
Next ChtObj

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a command to check whether there's a chart or listobject present in the sheet? Something that can return a boolean?

Comment: @Meet Sure, `If Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObject.Count > 0 Then`, if it's larger than 0 you have at least one chart, otherwise none

Comment: Yeah. That works. But how do we find which chart or object it is? For example, I want to delete all charts in that sheet, if there are any. Otherwise show a message that there are no charts. Now, I can get that using this count method, but how do I delete all the chart objects present on the sheet?